# Java: Search for an object inside a large list

Tags: java

I have a large list (about 12,000 objects) of custom Objects inside which I will have to search for a specific Object a number of times. As of now, I am mostly using brute force to find the object, but it becomes extremely slow as the list grows larger. This is how I search as of now:

```
List<MyObject> objectsToSearch; //List containing about 12000 objects
MyObject objectToCompare = new MyObject("this is a parameter"); //Object to compare with list

for(MyObject compareFrom : objectsToSearch){

    if(compareFrom.equals(objectToCompare)){

        System.out.println("Object found");
    }
}
```

Surely there must be a better way to achieve this. Increasing performance becomes especially important since I will be needing to perform this operation multiple times.

Despite my research I haven't found any detailed tutorial. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Is sorting and binary-searching an option for you. Or using a HashSet in the first place?

Comment: I would consider quick or binary search. Brute-force is definitely not the best option for you.

Comment: a) index the data with a `Map`. or b) use multiple threads. or c) sort the data somehow, and do a binary search. or d) use a read database, storing 12,000 items in memory to search them is probably not the wisest idea.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I had a feeling a `Map` would be an option to consider. However I've never worked with those, any good tutorials to suggest?

Answer (score 2):

Make your class `MyObject` implement the `Comparator` and then sort the list using **[Collections.sort()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_sort_comparable.htm)** and then you can apply **[Collections.binarySearch()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_binarysearch_comparator.htm)**

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you really need a List? It seems that you are just checking the object for *presence*. If you don't need to keep the order of the objects and if it's sufficient to keep each object only once, consider using a Set instead, most probably HashSet.

Do not forget to implement equals() and hashCode() for the objects you store otherwise HashSet will not work.

Comment: Actually I need the data from the object, the example above is widely simplified. I have seen that Sets may be an option, however I haven't found any good tutorials. Anything to suggest?

Comment: Have you tried Oracle Java Tutorial on Collections?

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented equals method for your custom class correctly you can use the contains(Object o) method.

```
if(objectsToSearch.contains(objectToCompare)){
    System.out.println("Object found");
```